# Spree Commerce: display multiple categories on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm trying to make a link that can open or go to other page that display several categories on one page, like this: [mugs, bags, and books](https://www.example.com/t/categories/mugs,bags,books)

Is it possible to achieve this without using deface or modifying any page?
Maybe a normal link like:
`https://www.example.com/t/categories/mugs,bags,books`
`https://www.example.com/products?taxon=1,3,5`

I've tried both of them. I get error from the former and get the first category from the latter.

If deface is the only solution, how to do it if I want the link to look like the first link?

If it helps, I use `rails 4.2.1` and `spree 3.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get this sort of functionality by default in Spree. You're going to have to come up with a custom action that is capable of accepting the multiple categories and returning the products filtered by that category.

Comment: I know how to create action for accepting multiple params. How do you suggest me make spree view return products filtered by those multiple params/categories?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this up by through the admin panel in 
"Products" --> "Taxonomies"

If you edit "Categories" and add subcategories of "Mugs", "Bags" and "Books" you should be able to get what you are after via

https://www.example.com/t/categories/